# How can you add a script reference to a page from a custom webpart?

Tags: 2007, jquery, javascript

I'm developing a custom webpart and I'd like to leverage jQuery for some of my client side functionality.  I found a few articles that lay out the following technique for adding a script reference to a page from a custom webpart.

In my CreateChildControls method I added this line:

```
ScriptLink.Register(this.Page, "/_layouts/1033/jquery.js", false);
```

Then ensured that the script file is being deployed as part of my feature.

But after following this example I get the following error:

```
Cannot make a cache safe URL for "/_layouts/1033/jquery.js", file not found. Please verify that the file exists under the layouts directory.
```

I can take that path string and throw it in the address bar after "http://%servername%" and the browser tries to download the script file so it's obviously there.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(this.Page, this.GetType(), insertuniquekeyhere, "/_layouts/1033/jquery.js");
```

See the [RegisterClientScriptInclude page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360649.aspx) for details. Other ScriptManager methods might also help.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to mark as answer I was on another project for a bit.