# How to add jQuery script to a custom visual webpart?

Tags: 2013, jquery, visual-web-part

Similar to some [previous](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/8568/how-can-you-add-a-script-reference-to-a-page-from-a-custom-webpart) [questions](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/31359/jquery-in-a-visual-webpart-wont-load-on-the-page-with-the-webpart), I'm trying to use jQuery in a visual web part but I keep getting that jQuery is undefined. I've added the jQuery script to SiteAssets as well as a script folder inside my visual webpart project, and tried referencing it in the ascx file with both:

```
<script src="~sitecollection/SiteAssets/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="./Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

And also in code behind, in the Page_Load method, with lines such as:

```
this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(this.GetType(), "custJquery1", "~/SiteAssets/jquery-1.9.1.min.js");
this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(this.GetType(), "custJquery2", "~sitecollection/SiteAssets/jquery-1.9.1.min.js");
this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(this.GetType(), "custJquery2", "/SiteAssets/jquery-1.9.1.min.js");
```

I've also tried not referencing jQuery anywhere because I thought maybe the page (Discussion board topics) I'm using the webpart may already have jQuery on it.

The javascript I am using to check the jquery in my ascx file is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function TheFunctionToDoTheWork() {
        if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
            alert('jQuery didnt load');
        }
        else
            alert("Ive never received this message");
    }

    // "Subscribe to the SharePoint "page load"
    _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push('TheFunctionToDoTheWork');
</script>
```

All I ever get is the alert that 'jQuery didnt load'. What might be wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is `src` attribute of tag. Try `<script src="/StyleLibrary/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" />` and take a look at [this article](http://www.solidq.com/sqj/Pages/Collaboration/Integrating-jQuery-in-SharePoint-2010.aspx)

**Edit** If you decide to store js in _layouts folder, use `<SharePoint:ScriptLink runat="server" ID="ScriptLinkJQuery" name="/Js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" Localizable="false" />`

Comment: As a note, SOD doesn't like the multiple periods in the JS name because of the Dictionary lookup. Consider renaming any JS files to use dashes and underscores only.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a late answer but this sums up the work that has been done in the past few months on this subject:

Here is some example code I used in a control for SOD, in a visual web-part it should be the same.

```
    // Running in a Control added to Master Page
    // Register the JavaScript file to the header
    ScriptLink.Register(
        this.Page,
        @"js/ajaxlibrary.js",
        false
    );

    // But tell the page to load it
    // at the end of the page
    string clientLoadjaxLibrary =
        "LoadSodByKey('js/ajaxlibrary.js');";
    SPPageContentManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(
        this,
        this.GetType(),
        "clientLoadjaxLibrary",
        clientLoadjaxLibrary
    );
```

for scriptlinks there syntax if you want it loaded on request is:

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="~sitecollection/Site Assets/js/jquery.js" runat="server" OnDemand="False" LoadAfterUI="True" />
```

also make sure you wrap your JQuery up like so to register it as a global library in sharepoint:

```
function $_global_jquery() {
    //jquery code here
}
```

calling this function either in a scriptblock on your required page/control or at the bottom of the JS file to load the library:

```
$_global_jquery();
```

All custom libraries should be wrapped up with that, also custom namespaces should be registered with SharePoint as well.

**On another note JQuery 1.10.2 is the only version that has no conflicts with any part of SharePoint. Older versions throw strange errors from time to time with $ conflicts.**

Comment: This is Great!)